# Geth LES Client. Only synchronize the last 50 headers?

Tags: go-ethereum, les

Using a [LES](https://github.com/zsfelfoldi/go-ethereum/wiki/Light-Ethereum-Subprotocol-%28LES%29) client, is it possible to only synchronize only some of the last headers on first run ?

I am not interested in the chain history.

I understand the security implications of not validating the full chain, but I believe that getting, say, the last 50 continuous headers from 5 different LES server nodes is good enough to assume that the chain I got is valid.